# Azure deployments when an AppService running/scaled to 2+ instances

Tags: powershell, azure, continuous-deployment

I'm working on a feature for our project that will continuously deploy to production. 
During development I have discovered that if deployment slots are used:

Staging swap to Production 
within a web role running multiple instances (aka scaled out mode), 
the swap Stage->Prod is happening only to 1 instance.

So the problem is that I may run staled/faulty code . 
The only way I found, so far:
1. Scale down
2. swap
3. Scale Up

the solution not quite efficient . Is there a way to hot swap all instances of  Web role ?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? We have the same issue.

Comment: @Mr.Flibble are you using a Web App (App service)? What are the symptoms?

Comment: What are you using for continuous deployment? Is it VSTS, or something else?

Comment: @MBen & @Rob Regan 

It's an 'App Service'. We're deploying using Powershell (on AppVeyor) using the following commands

1) `New-AzureWebsite    -Name sitename -Slot staging -Location "North Europe"`. 

2) `Publish-AzureWebsiteProject  -Name sitename -slot staging -Package path.zip`

3) `Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot  -Name sitename -Force`

We are scaled out to two instances, but after the swap it seems that one instance is dead and the other is updated correctly.

Comment: @Mr.Flibble so after deplyoment, in the Azure portal your instance count is correct, or `2` as expected, but only one of them is working properly?

Comment: @KaiZhao Yes, exactly.

Comment: How long have you waited after the swap? It may be that you need to give it a little time to update the 2nd instance as well.

Comment: @Mr.Flibble I have some idea why it didn't work out for OP, I will post it as an answer, but it may not resolve your problem. The problem you have may have something to do with you application's persistence

Comment: @Mr.Flibble I have an open ticket witm Azure team. so I have repro this issue in other environment. The key part is that I use 2 Large instances. My workaround is to restart the Jobs. more details on how to repro the bug : https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3717

Comment: @KaiZhao I got the same conversation about Persistence with Azure team. played around with it , same result

Comment: @Dorin hmm, the issue in github page does not seem to be the problem you originally wrote. Your ARR affinity changed after deployment, maybe you should disable it so it would not check. This post may help with your issue: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: @KaiZhao well it is the same issue. just behaviour is different. Played with ARR Affinity, no effect. wonder why ARR affinity is blamed for it

Comment: @KaiZhao  I did not use ARR affinity to make requests. so my requests are going through load balancer and hits stale instance randomly . I will provide fiddler session tomorrow.

Comment: @Dorin load balancer? Sorry I think you have `web role` instead of `app service` and I mis-read your original post. Mr Flibble has `AppService`, which should not have load balancer, unless it's the expensive `ASE`.. the github post you linked flags ARR Affinity. Anyways, if `web role` is still your case, we can look into that direction. First, do you have an instance count defined in your `cscfg` file?

Comment: @KaiZhao well, it is actually a AppService plan, edited the post title. The ARRAfinity is not used while making requests. So how Azure does know what instance to hit if I do not use ARR cookie in my request?

Comment: @Dorin Azure dose NOT know which instance to hit when it is disabled. So if your session data is maintained on the local host, your client will lose them when they hit another instance. You can try manage session data externally in many different approach, such as redis cache described in #2 link in my answer. Still, if disable ARRAfinity does not resolve your deployment problem, there might be something else

Comment: @KaiZhao I have not mentioned nor said anything about sessions or session data. We do not persist data in sessions . To make it more curious , my sample app that I used to repro the problem in a public environment, has no Database nor any post body. I do have a problem with a plain controller that is replying with a boolean "true" .

Comment: @Dorin I'm really curious since this seems to be something more obvious we missed. Mind sharing source of your sample app?

Answer (score 0):

We have deployment implementation following this Microsoft guidance.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing

The outcome instance count would persist after deployment

To create a Staging slot, -Slot is `Staging`

```
New-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName [resource group name] -Name [app name] -Slot [deployment slot name] -AppServicePlan [app service plan name]
```

To swap the slot

```
$ParametersObject = @{targetSlot  = "[slot name – e.g. “production”]"} 
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName [resource group name] -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots -ResourceName [app name]/[slot name] -Action slotsswap -Parameters $ParametersObject -ApiVersion 2015-07-01
```

Note you may need service principal for deployment to be able to interact with resource manager

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal

Updated 4/19 - 
I see there might be other persistence related issue that mess up the application after deployment, here are two examples that may help, but the issue would mostly be application specific

1. [Disabling ARR’s Instance Affinity in Windows Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites/)
2. [Azure Websites and stateful webApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089635/azure-websites-and-stateful-webapp)